Functional analysis question about operator on quantum wave functions
If I have two time-independent wave functions $\psi_{t_{1}}$ and $\psi_{t_{2}}$ and define an operator $\hat{U}$ such that $$\psi_{t_{2}} = \hat{U}_{t_{1},t_{2}}(\psi_{t_{1}})$$ and $$\psi_{t_{2}}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} U_{t_{1},t_{2}}(a, x-a) \psi_{t_{1}}(a)\, da.$$ Can the operator  $\hat{U}_{t_{1},t_{2}}$ be said to preserves the normalization of $\psi_{t_{2}}$ if for every real value $a$, the function $U_{t_{1},t_{2}}(a,b)$ behaves as a normalized function over over $b$?
I'm trying to understand if you can model the time evolution of $\psi$ with an operator $\hat{U}$ where the function $U(a,b)$ is some function that for every value $a$ can be thought of as defining an influence distribution, where it returns a scalar value that encodes the influence of the probability amplitude of $\psi_{t_{1}}(a)$ on the probability amplitude of $\psi_{t_{2}}(a + b)$, or conversely, if the probability amplitude $\psi_{t_{2}}(x)$ can be constructed from the probability amplitude of every location $a$ in $\psi_{t_{1}}$ multiplied by some value that encodes the influence of $\psi_{t_{1}}(a)$ at time $t_1$ on $\psi_{t_{2}}(x)$ at time $t_2$?
I noticed that if the above is conceptually valid, you can get the equivalent of a light-cone, as you could say that if the operator $\hat{U}$ represents the time evolution of from $t_{1}$ to $t_{2}$ then $U_{t_{1},t_{2}}(a,b)$ must be zero where $b > ct$ and $b < -ct$ because no information about the probability amplitude of $\psi_{t_{1}}(a)$ can influence the probability amplitude of any position beyond a radius of $ct$ in $\psi_{t_{2}}$. This, in theory should limit any information in the system from leaking beyond the light horizon even with recursive application of $\hat{U}$.
You could then rewrite the original definition above as $$\hat{U}_{t_{1},t_{2}}(\psi_{t_{1}}) = \int_{x-c(t_{2}-t_{1})}^{x+c(t_{2}-t_{1})} U_{t_{1},t_{2}}(a, x-a) \psi_{t_{1}}(a)\, da.$$
I tried working out the proof myself but got stumped by my very rusty calculus skills.
\begin{align*}
    1 &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \psi^*_{t_{2}}(x)  \psi_{t_{2}}(x)\,dx  \\
      &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (U_{t_{1},t_{2}}(\psi_{t_{1}}))^* (U_{t_{1},t_{2}}(\psi_{t_{1}}))\,dx \\
      &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} U_{t_{1},t_{2}}(b, x-b) \psi_{t_{1}}(b) \, db \right)^* \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} U_{t_{1},t_{2}}(a, x-a) \psi_{t_{1}}(a) \, da \right)\, dx \\
\end{align*}
I tried substitution of $u = x - b$ and $v = x - a$ then $du = dv = dx$
\begin{align*}
      &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} U_{t_{1},t_{2}}(a, u) U_{t_{1},t_{2}}(b, u)^* \psi_{t_{1}}(a) \psi_{t_{1}}(b)^* \, du \, da \, db.\\
      &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} U_{t_{1},t_{2}}(a, u) U_{t_{1},t_{2}}(b, u)^*  \psi_1(a) \psi_1(b)^* \, da \, db \right) \, du. \\
\end{align*}
But I then got stuck here. I think that if you assert that $\psi_{t_{1}}$ is normalized then $U_{t_{1},t_{2}}(b, u)$ must be normalized over $u$, but I lack the skills to get the proof the rest of the way.

For a complex, separable (or finite-dimensional) Hilbert space $H$, there is always a unitary operator $U$ such that for two given vectors $x,y\in H$ it holds that $x=Uy$ as long as $|x|=|y|$.
